# Is there any way of stripping all javascript from a string in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, strip

I have the following php code:

```
$mystr = "<script>window.onload = function(){console.log('Hi')}</script>";
$mystr .= "<div onmouseover='alert('Hi')'></div";
```

What i want is to strip all kind of javascript from $mystr.

I am trying the following code but it keeps the onmouseover event.

```
$mystr = strip_tags($mystr,'<div>');
```

I want to remove the onmouseover or any othe inline javascript code too.

I am actually trying to achieve the above in wordpress. so as far as i know there is no HTML Purifier in wordpress.

Comment: Why do you need that? Explain the original task

Comment: So, you need some kind of dom parser that will remove attributes x, y, z, and tag q.

Comment: I need it since this string data is actually going to be posted by an html page. I will receive that string from the $_POST method and then if there is any malicious javascript code in it, i will try to remove it.

Comment: Since this was mentioned as being a Wordpress project, may I refer you to : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses hope that helps!  I believe it will work for your need.  I am not posting this as a 'solution' but I believe this may be your answer.

Comment: @JoshuaChavanne Thank you very much. Just what i expected. However i am getting a problem concerning one parameter in the wp_kses. wp_kses also strips style attributes from the tags i allowed. My code is following. $allowed_html = array(
   'div' => array(
    'title' => array(),
    'style' => array(),
    'class' => array()
   )
  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how strip_tags works, eg:

```
$html = '<foo>hello<bar>world</bar></foo>';
$fixed = strip_tags($html, '<bar>');
echo $fixed;
```

outputs:

```
hello<bar>world</bar>
```

It doesn't understand the DOM, it doesn't understand javascript. it's essentially doing:

```
$fixed = str_replace('<script>', '', $html);
```

The only "smarts" it has is recognizing that tags can have attributes and deleting those as well.

If you want to remove a tag and all of its contents, then you should be using a DOM parser, and deleting the unwanted nodes (aka tags) and their children from the tree entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want something like [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/), which will let you specify a white/blacklist of tags and attributes to permit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code from one year now to clean user input it always works for me.

```
function xss_clean($data)
{
// Fix &entity\n;
$data = str_replace(array('&amp;','&lt;','&gt;'), array('&amp;amp;','&amp;lt;','&amp;gt;'), $data);
$data = preg_replace('/(&#*\w+)[\x00-\x20]+;/u', '$1;', $data);
$data = preg_replace('/(&#x*[0-9A-F]+);*/iu', '$1;', $data);
$data = html_entity_decode($data, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');

// Remove any attribute starting with "on" or xmlns
$data = preg_replace('#(<[^>]+?[\x00-\x20"\'])(?:on|xmlns)[^>]*+>#iu', '$1>', $data);

// Remove javascript: and vbscript: protocols
$data = preg_replace('#([a-z]*)[\x00-\x20]*=[\x00-\x20]*([`\'"]*)[\x00-\x20]*j[\x00-\x20]*a[\x00-\x20]*v[\x00-\x20]*a[\x00-\x20]*s[\x00-\x20]*c[\x00-\x20]*r[\x00-\x20]*i[\x00-\x20]*p[\x00-\x20]*t[\x00-\x20]*:#iu', '$1=$2nojavascript...', $data);
$data = preg_replace('#([a-z]*)[\x00-\x20]*=([\'"]*)[\x00-\x20]*v[\x00-\x20]*b[\x00-\x20]*s[\x00-\x20]*c[\x00-\x20]*r[\x00-\x20]*i[\x00-\x20]*p[\x00-\x20]*t[\x00-\x20]*:#iu', '$1=$2novbscript...', $data);
$data = preg_replace('#([a-z]*)[\x00-\x20]*=([\'"]*)[\x00-\x20]*-moz-binding[\x00-\x20]*:#u', '$1=$2nomozbinding...', $data);

// Only works in IE: <span style="width: expression(alert('Ping!'));"></span>
$data = preg_replace('#(<[^>]+?)style[\x00-\x20]*=[\x00-\x20]*[`\'"]*.*?expression[\x00-\x20]*\([^>]*+>#i', '$1>', $data);
$data = preg_replace('#(<[^>]+?)style[\x00-\x20]*=[\x00-\x20]*[`\'"]*.*?behaviour[\x00-\x20]*\([^>]*+>#i', '$1>', $data);
$data = preg_replace('#(<[^>]+?)style[\x00-\x20]*=[\x00-\x20]*[`\'"]*.*?s[\x00-\x20]*c[\x00-\x20]*r[\x00-\x20]*i[\x00-\x20]*p[\x00-\x20]*t[\x00-\x20]*:*[^>]*+>#iu', '$1>', $data);

// Remove namespaced elements (we do not need them)
$data = preg_replace('#</*\w+:\w[^>]*+>#i', '', $data);
do
{
    // Remove really unwanted tags
    $old_data = $data;
    $data = preg_replace('#</*(?:applet|b(?:ase|gsound|link)|embed|frame(?:set)?|i(?:frame|layer)|l(?:ayer|ink)|meta|object|s(?:cript|tyle)|title|xml)[^>]*+>#i', '', $data);
}
while ($old_data !== $data);

// we are done...
return $data;
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: "always works for you" isn't good enough. there **WILL** be malformed html that causes this to fail. you just haven't encountered it yet. the only proper way to safely manipulate arbitrary html is with a DOM parser.

Comment: Well i appreciate your comment but as software it cannot be perfect(Basic software engineering concept.). If you think this code is not perfect for Striping javascript please try to find the injection for that to deface it, it will be appreciated, i myself tested all type of XSS injection against this code.

Comment: who said anything about xss? I'm talking malformed html.

Comment: have you got a chance to read a question title even :Is there any way of stripping all javascript from a string in PHP?

Comment: yes. like I said: Use a dom parser, find and delete all `<javascript>` nodes in the DOM tree, and the code will vanish. anything else is going to be at very high risk of corrupting the document.